# Checking for specific characters in a String

Tags: c, string, parsing

I have a string that looks like this:

```
char *string = "This is a\r string\r\nTTTT";
```

Where I want to check a string (like the one above for the `\r` and `\r\n` characters, however, simply using `strcmp` doesn't work. For instance:

```
if (strcmp(string, "\r\n") == 0) {     
    if (strcmp(string, "\n) == 0) {
        printf("The string contains both a newline, and "\r\n" characters");
    }
}
```

`memcmp` and `strncmp` don't seem to work either:

```
if (memcmp(string, "\r\n", 2) == 0) {
    if (memcmp(string, "\n", 1) == 0) {
        printf("The string contains both a newline, and "\r\n" characters");
    }
}
```

I also tried this (Which somewhat works, but then doesn't).

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
    if (string[i] == '\n') {
        if (strcmp(string, "\r\n") == 0) {
            printf("The string contains both a newline, and "\r\n" characters");
        }
    }
}
```

Where the lasted method I tried does indeed find the newline character, but fails to find the "\r\n" characters. And the other two above simply don't work at all, any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear what, exactly, the expected behaviour should be. Finding the first of either `\r` or `\n`?  That would be strpbrk(). *All* occurences of either? Do you want to *tokenize* the input string, using those characters as delimiters? Please be more precise. Either way, familiarize yourself with [the string functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), there's something for every need in there.

Comment: FInding a string where "\r\n" is not at the end of the line, and also contains a "\n" character.

Comment: Since in my string, "\r\n" is not at the end of the line, and is not following the windows convention of the "\r\n" characters being at the end, while UNIX having the "\n" convention at the end. Basically, it's an error case where a string is not following the correct convention.

Comment: To detect 'mixed line-endings' you would need to scan for `\r` and check whether it is followed by `\n`. If it is/isn't, you keep scanning `\r`'s until you find one that isn't/is followed by `\n`.

Comment: In your code fragments, you do not correctly escape the `"` in the `"The string contains both a newline, and "\r\n" characters"` strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char * someString = "This is a\r string\r\nTTTT";
    if(strstr(someString, "\r\n") != NULL) {
        puts("We hit \\r\\n");
    }

    if(strstr(someString, "\n") != NULL) {
        puts("We hit \\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This only checks for "\r\n" but not the other "\n" ? What I mean is, I might have a string (given to me) that only has "\r\n" but no newline, so your if statement would execute anyway.

Comment: You can use the same ```strstr``` call to check for ```\n``` too, I added an example. Any logic you need to do with that can be achieved by ordering those comparison statements how-ever you want them.

Comment: Strange, it still doesn't seem to return true? Not sure if it's undefined behaviour or something else is going on. Code Rot or something else.

Comment: It seems the first if statement fails , "\r\n" is never found oddly enough.

Comment: @KEDE: Works fine for me. Are you sure you copy & pasted it correctly, and run the correct executable?

Comment: Yep and yep, it's worth nothing that this string is from a file I'm reading in, possibly something happening with the buffer,and a possible required call to fflush?

Comment: @KEDE: That's a different question, and one we cannot solve without seeing the code. Note that `fflush()` is well-defined for **output** streams only. Line-end handling is also depending on whether you opened the file in text or binary mode, and which OS you are working on.